# Per-user MSI non-elevated by default - how to show an elevation prompt for writing to a folder?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uac

I have an MSI built via WiX, it's per-user and doesn't display the UAC prompt if the user has rights to the destination folder. However, if the destination folder is in Program Files, it errors with "Insuficient privileges".

How can I show a [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) prompt in the case the destination folder is not writable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really work that way.  Per User installs should never require elevation and should never write to Program Files as that's a per machine location. Instead it should install to %LocalAppData%\Programs\Company\Product.

Read the following for a lot more background information.  Parts apply and parts may be beyond scope ( dual per-user / per-machine requirements ):

[Authoring a single package for Per-User or Per-Machine Installation context in Windows 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2009/09/02/authoring-a-single-package-for-per-user-or-per-machine-installation-context-in-windows-7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I want to let others who come across it that it is indeed possible.

As was mentioned in the previous answer, conventional per-user installs should not require admin rights. However, I came across a perfectly valid situation where I needed to run a custom action which required admin rights. Requiring my users to launch the MSI with msiexec from a command line with elevated privileges did not seem like an acceptable solution.

It doesn't seem like this should be so difficult, but luckily I stumbled onto the answer in [this post](https://sourceforge.net/p/wix/mailman/message/26220559/): The Package/@InstallScope attribute doesn’t support per-user, elevated packages! So just omit it in your Package definition:

```
<!-- NOTE: If you need to create a per-user installation (meaning it's not -->
<!-- visible in Add/Remove Programs from other logons) that prompts for -->
<!-- elevation, omit both the Package/@InstallPrivileges="elevated" and
<!-- Package/@InstallScope="perUser". -->
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />
```

Don't forget to leave ALLUSERS undefined, as well. I described this further on my blog:

[How to Elevate a Per User Installer Using WiX](http://www.codingmatter.com/coding/2016/11/19/elevate-per-user-installer.html)